# grails 3 defaultGrailsjava.lang.DoubleConverter parse Double

Tags: mysql, grails, save, double

I'm using grails 3 with it_IT as locale but when I save a double value, the decimal digits aren't saved.
i.e. if I try to save 1,23 I got 123

If I force the defaultLocale to "en","US" the double is saved correctly.

I see that the was some workaround in grails 2 implementing the ValueConverter class, but I can't use this method because I can't find out the ValueConverter class.

Comment: "...but I can't use this method because I can't find out the ValueConverter class" - The `ValueConverter` class is in the `grails.databinding.converters` package in Grails 3.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/fca9b41383b2e91acb3493f949fba737f10fde3f/grails-databinding/src/main/groovy/grails/databinding/converters/ValueConverter.java.

Comment: Some documentation on writing a `ValueConverter` is available at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.6/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding.

Comment: in grails 3.0.11 I can't find the class org.grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter

Comment: "in grails 3.0.11 I can't find the class org.grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter" - In Grails 3.0.11 I don't think there is a `org.grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter`.  See my comment above.  The `ValueConverter` class is now in the `grails.databinding.converters` package.

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.0.11/grails-databinding/src/main/groovy/grails/databinding/converters/ValueConverter.java.

Comment: Ok, i see, it's correct as you told me probably there is an error in the documentation (in the documentation example there is org.grails...).

Comment: In case of double I tried in getTargetType() to put return double. I see that getTargetType is called, But the convert method is not called saving a double value